# Updating a large record set in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to update a single field across a large set of records. Normally, I would just run a quick SQL update statement from the console and be done with it, but this is a utility that end users need to be able to run in this app.

So, here's my code:

```
users = User.find(:all, :select => 'id, flag')
users.each do |u|
  u.flag = false
  u.save
end
```

I'm afraid this is just going to take a while as the number of users increases (current sitting at around 35k, adding 2-5k a week). Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to update all records, the easiest way is to use [#update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001787):

```
User.update_all(:flag => false)
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
UPDATE users SET flag = 'f'
```

(The exact SQL will be different depending on your adapter)

The #update_all method also accepts conditions:

```
User.update_all({:flag => false}, {:created_on => 3.weeks.ago .. 5.hours.ago})
```

Also, #update_all can be combined with named scopes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :inactive, lambda {{:conditions => {:last_login_at => 2.years.ago .. 2.weeks.ago}}
end

User.inactive.update_all(:flag => false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ActiveRecord's [execute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#M001423) method to execute the update SQL. Something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE users SET flag=0')
```